# SystemStackError: when parsing SCIM 2.0 filter query using Parslet

Tags: ruby, scim2, parslet

I am writing a SCIM 2.0 filter parser using Parslet. When I try to parse the following query, I end up with a SystemStackError.

'title pr or userType eq "Intern"'

I have converted the ABNF notation from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#page-21 into a Parslet parser shown in the example code.

```rb
class Filter < Parslet::Parser
  root :filter

  # FILTER = attrExp / logExp / valuePath / *1"not" "(" FILTER ")"
  rule(:filter) do
    attribute_expression | logical_expression | value_path | not_op >> lparen >> filter >> rparen
  end

  # valuePath = attrPath "[" valFilter "]" ; FILTER uses sub-attributes of a parent attrPath
  rule(:value_path) do
    attribute_path.as(:attribute) >> lbracket >> value_filter >> rbracket
  end

  # valFilter = attrExp / logExp / *1"not" "(" valFilter ")"
  rule(:value_filter) do
    attribute_expression | logical_expression | not_op >> lparen >> value_filter >> rparen
  end

  # attrExp = (attrPath SP "pr") / (attrPath SP compareOp SP compValue)
  rule(:attribute_expression) do
    (attribute_path.as(:attribute) >> space >> presence) | attribute_path.as(:attribute) >> space >> comparison_operator.as(:comparison_operator) >> space >> comparison_value.as(:comparison_value)
  end

  # logExp = FILTER SP ("and" / "or") SP FILTER
  rule(:logical_expression) do
    filter >> space >> (and_op | or_op) >> space >> filter
  end

  # compValue = false / null / true / number / string ; rules from JSON (RFC 7159)
  rule(:comparison_value) do
    falsey | null | truthy | number | string
  end

  # compareOp = "eq" / "ne" / "co" / "sw" / "ew" / "gt" / "lt" / "ge" / "le"
  rule(:comparison_operator) do
    equal | not_equal | contains | starts_with | ends_with |
      greater_than | less_than | less_than_equals | greater_than_equals
  end

  # attrPath = [URI ":"] ATTRNAME *1subAttr ; SCIM attribute name ; URI is SCIM "schema" URI
  rule(:attribute_path) do
    (uri >> colon).repeat(0, 1) >> attribute_name >> sub_attribute.repeat(0, 1)
  end

  # ATTRNAME  = ALPHA *(nameChar)
  rule(:attribute_name) do
    alpha >> name_character.repeat(0, nil)
  end

  # nameChar = "-" / "_" / DIGIT / ALPHA
  rule(:name_character) { hyphen | underscore | digit | alpha }

  # subAttr = "." ATTRNAME ; a sub-attribute of a complex attribute
  rule(:sub_attribute) { dot >> attribute_name }

  # uri = 1*ALPHA 1*(":" 1*ALPHA)
  rule(:uri) do
    # alpha.repeat(1, nil) >> (colon >> (alpha.repeat(1, nil) | version)).repeat(1, nil)
    str('urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:') >> (
      str('core:2.0:User') |
      str('core:2.0:Group') | (
        str('extension') >>
        colon >>
        alpha.repeat(1) >>
        colon >>
        version >>
        colon >>
        alpha.repeat(1)
      )
    )
  end
  rule(:presence) { str('pr').as(:presence) }
  rule(:and_op) { str('and').as(:and) }
  rule(:or_op) { str('or').as(:or) }
  rule(:not_op) { str('not').repeat(0, 1).as(:not) }
  rule(:falsey) { str('false').as(:false) }
  rule(:truthy) { str('true').as(:true) }
  rule(:null) { str('null').as(:null) }
  rule(:number) do
    str('-').maybe >> (
      str('0') | (match('[1-9]') >> digit.repeat)
    ) >> (
      str('.') >> digit.repeat(1)
    ).maybe >> (
      match('[eE]') >> (str('+') | str('-')).maybe >> digit.repeat(1)
    ).maybe
  end
  rule(:equal) { str('eq') }
  rule(:not_equal) { str('ne') }
  rule(:contains) { str('co') }
  rule(:starts_with) { str('sw') }
  rule(:ends_with) { str('ew') }
  rule(:greater_than) { str('gt') }
  rule(:less_than) { str('lt') }
  rule(:greater_than_equals) { str('ge') }
  rule(:less_than_equals) { str('le') }
  rule(:string) do
    quote >> (str('\\') >> any | str('"').absent? >> any).repeat >> quote
  end
  rule(:lparen) { str('(') }
  rule(:rparen) { str(')') }
  rule(:lbracket) { str('[') }
  rule(:rbracket) { str(']') }
  rule(:digit) { match('\d') }
  rule(:quote) { str('"') }
  rule(:single_quote) { str("'") }
  rule(:space) { match('\s') }
  rule(:alpha) { match['a-zA-Z'] }
  rule(:dot) { str('.') }
  rule(:colon) { str(':') }
  rule(:hyphen) { str('-') }
  rule(:underscore) { str('_') }
  rule(:version) { digit >> dot >> digit }
end
```

I am expecting that Parslet should be able to handle the recursion safely instead of raising a SystemStackError. The base atom sets the `def cached?` to return true by default. If I monkey patch the Atom base class to return false from the `cached?` method, then I am able to parse this query. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always consume something before you recurse.

For example: 
Don't define a list of numbers as

```
NumList = NumList >> "," >> NumList | Number
```

Defined it as

```
NumList = Number >> ("," >> NumList).maybe
```

or even

```
NumList = Number >> ("," >> Number).repeat(0)
```

So for logican_expression...

```
 # logExp = FILTER SP ("and" / "or") SP FILTER
  rule(:logical_expression) do
    filter >> space >> (and_op | or_op) >> space >> filter
  end
```

You need the first `filter` to be something that can't be a logical_expression.

```
   # FILTER = attrExp / logExp / valuePath / *1"not" "(" FILTER ")"
  rule(:filter) do
    logical_expression | filter_atom 
  end

  rule(:filter_atom) do
    (not_op? >> lparen >> filter >> rparen) | attribute_expression  | value_path 
  end

  # logExp = FILTER SP ("and" / "or") SP FILTER
  rule(:logical_expression) do
    filter_atom >> space >> (and_op | or_op) >> space >> filter
  end
```